# Hypothesis testing

Tags: normal-distribution

A survey conducted by the ministry of health in 9% of parents described their children as overweight. Results from a study by University students claims that atleast 15% of parents described their children as overweight. You take a sample of 750 parents and that 68 out of the 750 described their children as overweight.

Q1. formulate and test the hypothesis that the proportion of parents who describe their children as overweight is less than the 15% claim by the University students.

So here my view is that this is a single population proportion with

P=  68/750 = 0.091 , n= 750 ,
π= 0.15 with π being the null hypothesized proportion

Ho : p =< 0
H1 : p> 0

the Z-stat =  (p-π)/ √ [ π(1-π)/ 750 ]
    (0.091-0.15) / √ [ 0.15(1-0.15)/ 750]

Z = 4.5

my Standard normal table does not give the corresponding value of 4.5 it shows up to Z= 3.9 so I cant find the P-value

somehow I think I misinterpreted the the data. it could be two population proportion.

please help!!

Comment: Statistical tables for the normal distribution don't generally go out that far but you can say that the p-value is less than 0.001.which may be less than the significance level that you are testing at. Incidentally you should be looking at -4.5 compared to -3.9 since the test is one-sided to the left.

Comment: You should try Wolphram Alpha, type "Z is standard normal; P(Z> 4.5)" there